# Connecting to an oracle database through Django

Tags: python, django, oracle

I would like to connect to an existing oracle database though Django and write a select statement to query the results. I am a beginner to Django and would like to know the steps to follow to achieve the same.

I did change the settings.py file to reflect the changes

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
         'NAME': 'name',
         'USER': 'username',
         'PASSWORD': 'password',
         'HOST': 'host.com',
         'PORT': '1521',
  }
}
```

Comment: You can refer django offical documentation which gives a very clear idea about how to use. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/

Comment: What is the error???

Comment: The error I'm currently getting is
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13565 may help you

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the entries like below in settings.py file.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
         'NAME': 'host.com:1521/dbname',
         'USER': 'username',
         'PASSWORD': 'password',
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below steps to connect to the Oracle database using Django.

1. Add database connection details in `settings.py`

---

If you are connecting through a service

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
       'NAME': 'host.db.com:1540/oracle_service.db.com',
       'USER': 'user',
       'PASSWORD': 'password',
   }
}
```

If you are connecting through SID

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'xe',
        'USER': 'a_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'a_password',
        'HOST': 'dbprod01ned.mycompany.com',
        'PORT': '1540',
    }
}
```

---

2. Install the `cx_Oracle` [library](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#quick-start-cx-oracle-installation) in your Django project.
3. Go your application's `views.py` file and add the below code.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.db import connection
    
def process(request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
         cursor.execute("select * from YOUR_TABLE")
         columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
         return JsonResponse([
            dict(zip(columns, row))
            for row in cursor.fetchall()
         ], safe=False)
```

This API will output the query result in JSON format.
Link to the official [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'db_user',
        'USER': 'shema_name',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'ip_or_domain',
        'PORT': '1521',
    }
}
```